# A very simple lightweight video editor

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, media, codec

I want to make an editor that does the following:

1) takes an mp3 audio file

2) Takes a picture --a jpg file

3) Outputs a simple video format e.g. .mov which consists of the jpg file with the mp3 file in the background

4) Does NOTHING else

I want to use this as a project to learn just the basics of all this stuff however I do not want to code basic things by hand. Where do I start and what key steps do I take to accomplish this?

I am decent with PHP and Java and do not mind learning Python for this. I actually would ideally want to write this in Python to gain experience.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code such a solution yourself - forget Python, compile ffmpeg and use it's classes directly from your code after you carefully read them (or maybe use [pyffmpeg](http://code.google.com/p/pyffmpeg/), which still requires you to know ffmpeg internals).

However, I'm pretty sure that what you want could be done with ffmpeg executable alone from command line - but that way your Python code would end as a wrapper around os.Popen (it's quite popular solution actually).

I think it's a matter of what level of understanding you're aiming at: either you're ok with reading ffmpeg docs and believing it's going to work (then: use Python), or you need to dive deep into ffmpeg sources to gain real understanding what's going on (which I don't have, btw) - and then using pythonic bindings will just stand in your way.

I have needed ffmpeg (from django) a few times already and never had to do anything more than just assemble a list with ffmpeg command line args. On the other hand I would very much like to actually understand what the hell I'm doing, but no one seemed interested in paying me for groking ffmpeg sources. :-(

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you could do this all from the [mencoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MEncoder) commandline (use -speed option I think; might need to give it a duplicate of your jpg for every few seconds of video you want as it can only slow things down by a factor of 100 at the most).

Answer (score 0):

If you opt for the ffmpeg CLI solution, or need a process to try and replicate with the libraries directly, the relevant CLI command would be the straightforward:

```
ffmpeg -i input.jpg -i input.mp3 output.mov
```